# How to get the value of 'data.isnull().sum()' at Python

Tags: python

When I use this code at Python

```
train.isnull().sum()
```

I got the value like below. And I want to remove automatically after 'for' methods if the null number is more than 20000. 
 
I am thinking list, for and drop methods. But I dont know well how to make it concretely.
 Could you give me some solution?

```
id                         0
asins                  31379
brand                    984
categories             22000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
train[[c for (c, v) in train.isnull().sum().iteritems() if v < 20000]]
```

---

`train.isnull().sum().iteritems()` allows to loop over the column and count for the column. `train[[c for ...]]` retains the columns for which the null count is under the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

`mask = train.isnull().sum() < 20000` is a boolean-valued Series whose index labels match column labels in `train`.
Therefore, `train.loc[:, mask]` to select columns from `train` where `mask` is True:

```
train.loc[:, train.isnull().sum() < 20000]
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2019)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan, 1], size=(10,5)))
mask = df.isnull().sum()
print(mask)
# 0    8
# 1    5
# 2    5
# 3    6
# 4    5
# dtype: int64
print(df.loc[:, mask])
```

yields

```
     1    2    4
0  NaN  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  NaN
4  1.0  1.0  NaN
5  1.0  NaN  1.0
6  1.0  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  1.0  1.0
8  NaN  1.0  1.0
9  1.0  NaN  NaN
```